# How do I return only the last score a student has received by date?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have been trying to figure out how to gather the Last Score a student has received on a yearly test, but the only promising way I've been able to come up with is using the MAX function.  Where it all goes wrong is when I have to GROUP BY the other fields I'm returning in the result.  If I could leave off the Studenttestscore_Numscore field from the GROUP BY, I think it would work, but I'm not able to do so.  How can I write this to return only the last score received for every student in the database, based on the Test_Date?

The way I have it written below returns all scores that are different for each student. I believe it would work if it allowed me to remove Studenttestscore_Numscore from the GROUP BY, but it doesn't.

Right now because I have to include it to get the MAX function to work I get every score the student made on this yearly assessment unless it's the same as a previous score.

Thank you

```
SELECT
    ps.students.student_number,
    ps.test.name                  AS test_name,
    ps.studenttestscore.numscore  AS Studenttestscore_Numscore,
    MAX(ps.studenttest.test_date)      AS test_date
    
FROM
    ps.studenttestscore
    INNER JOIN ps.studenttest ON ps.studenttest.id = ps.studenttestscore.studenttestid
    INNER JOIN ps.students ON ps.studenttest.studentid = ps.students.id
    INNER JOIN ps.testscore ON ps.studenttestscore.testscoreid = ps.testscore.id
    INNER JOIN ps.test ON ps.test.id = ps.testscore.testid
    
WHERE
        ps.test.id = 269
    AND ps.testscore.id = 439
    
GROUP BY 
    ps.students.student_number,
    ps.test.name,
    ps.studenttestscore.numscore
```

Comment: Could you not get rid of `MAX` and order by date desc?

Comment: These might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Refer this on how to use aggregate with PARTITION and conditions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851417/how-to-evaluate-rows-and-get-the-max-value-based-on-multiple-columns

Comment: You can use RANK over order by date desc in a CTE and keep the 1's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MAX(...) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ...)` to keep only the last values of one column and then get the maximum of another column:

```sql
SELECT s.student_number,
       MAX(t.name) AS test_name,
       MAX(sts.numscore) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY st.test_date)
         AS Studenttestscore_Numscore,
       MAX(st.test_date) AS test_date
FROM   ps.studenttestscore sts
       INNER JOIN ps.studenttest st ON st.id = sts.studenttestid
       INNER JOIN ps.students s     ON st.studentid = s.id
       INNER JOIN ps.testscore ts   ON sts.testscoreid = ts.id
       INNER JOIN ps.test t         ON t.id = ts.testid
WHERE  t.id = 269
AND    ts.id = 439
GROUP BY 
       s.student_number,
       t.id
```

or order the row for each partition using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and then filter to only get the latest rows:

```sql
SELECT student_number,
       name AS test_name,
       numscore AS Studenttestscore_Numscore,
       test_date
FROM   (
  SELECT s.student_number,
         t.name,
         sts.numscore,
         st.test_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY s.student_number, t.id
           ORDER BY st.test_date DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   ps.studenttestscore sts
         INNER JOIN ps.studenttest st ON st.id = sts.studenttestid
         INNER JOIN ps.students s     ON st.studentid = s.id
         INNER JOIN ps.testscore ts   ON sts.testscoreid = ts.id
         INNER JOIN ps.test t         ON t.id = ts.testid
  WHERE  t.id = 269
  AND    ts.id = 439
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to use `row_number()` for things like this.
I write a subquery for the data that has multiple records that I'm trying to pull the latest of, and include a rownum that is partitioned/ordered accordingly, then join on rownum=1. No grouping is needed.

So for your query, to pull the latest record per student/test ID, it would end up being:

```
SELECT
    ps.students.student_number,
    ps.test.name                  AS test_name,
    ps.studenttestscore.numscore  AS Studenttestscore_Numscore,
    st.test_date
    
FROM
    ps.studenttestscore
    INNER JOIN (
        select *, rownum = row_number()over(partition by studentid, testid order by test_date desc)
        from ps.studenttest
    ) st ON st.id = ps.studenttestscore.studenttestid and st.rownum = 1
    INNER JOIN ps.students ON st.studentid = ps.students.id
    INNER JOIN ps.testscore ON ps.studenttestscore.testscoreid = ps.testscore.id
    INNER JOIN ps.test ON ps.test.id = ps.testscore.testid
    
WHERE
        ps.test.id = 269
```

This is assuming that the `testid` field is available in your `ps.studenttest` table since it needs to be included in the partition, but I don't know your schema so you'd have to modify accordingly if that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use returning values from **`DENSE_RANK()`** analytic function in which grouping by `ps.students.student_number` column is applied while descendingly sorted by `ps.studenttest.test_date` column in order to pick the latest matching record and remove the current `GROUP BY` clause such as

```sql
SELECT s.student_number,
       t.name AS test_name,
       sts.numscore AS Studenttestscore_Numscore,
       st.test_date,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY s.student_number ORDER BY st.test_date DESC) AS rank_latest_first
  FROM ps.studenttestscore sts
  JOIN ps.studenttest st
    ON st.id = sts.studenttestid
  JOIN ps.students s
    ON st.studentid = s.id
  JOIN ps.testscore ts
    ON sts.testscoreid = ts.id
  JOIN ps.test t
    ON t.id = ts.testid
 WHERE t.id = 269
   AND ts.id = 439
 ORDER BY rank_latest_first
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

where **`WITH TIES`** option provides to return multiple rows whenever there are latest dates more than one for an individual student.

The version of the DB should be *`12c+`* in order to be able to use **`FETCH`** clause.